# eXist-db installing MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, exist-db

Does anyone know the steps to correctly install the MySQL JDBC driver into eXist-db for MacOS?  I’m following http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/HowTo/SQLDatabases/QueryingSQLDatabases, but am stuck at 1.2.  Everything I try results in the error

`exerr:ERROR sql:get-connection() Cannot find database driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [at line 4, column 20]`

I’ve installed mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar into

```
/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Java/
/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/lib/user/
/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/lib/user/
/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/etc/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
```

And none of these locations resolved the error.  I must be missing a step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with eXist-db 5?

It is important to register the JDBC driver jar file in eXist-db. The jar file is placed in the $EXIST_HOME$/lib directory and the dependency on the jar file must be registered in eXist-db by adding an entry similar to the following in etc/startup.xml where the relativePath is the relative path to the jar file from the lib directory.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.18</version>
  <relativePath>jdbc/mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar</relativePath>
</dependency>
```